# "Anyone have an extra apartment there?"

Tags: ellipsis, conversational-deletion

> *Anyone have an extra apartment there?*

This quote is from an English native speaker. Why "anyone have"?

This could be an elliptical question, but I'd expect native speakers to ask a question using an affirmative sentence as in:

> Anyone knows what happened?

Here is the full quote:

> Friends. Hi! Sitting here on a Friday night brainstorming honeymoon
>   options with David. Who has ideas?!? Where is a great place to visit
>   at the end of March? We have ideas all over the place. One option we
>   are thinking about Paris ... **anyone have** an extra apartment there?

If it is an elliptical question, what do you think is more common in everyday spoken English? Elliptical or questions in affirmative forms?

**Edit:**

Thanks to everyone for answering. I was looking for [the full meaning and etymology of an idiom](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/19/messages/365.html) when I came across this quote which serves as a real world example:

> In Reply to: (Correcting omission) posted by R. Berg on February 25,
>   2003
>
> : : : **Anyone know** the origin of the idiom or phrase "Throw the book at
>   em." I realize it means prosecute someone to the fullest extent of the
>   law, a law enforcement term, but does anyone really know where it came
>   from and when it first began being used?

Comment: "Anyone have ...?" is okay, but "Anyone knows ...?" is not quite okay; it should be "Anyone know ...?"

Comment: I couldn't venture a guess on "which is more common." I will say this, though – neither form is rare in spoken English. Also, your questions asks about "spoken English," but you example looks like it was from written English.

Comment: Yes, it was from a written text. It was a comment on Facebook. I thought it is a written text of spoken nature. I didn't feel it is formal. However, I'm interested in how people speak in general.

Comment: it's elliptical to my ear, & perfectly natural in speech or speech-like writing - missing the "*does* anyone…" Similarly "Does anyone know.." or "Has anyone seen…"

Comment: I've always though "Anyone knows ...?"! as in "Who knows what might happen?". I understand that "who" is a question word. But hey, we also say "You're leaving now?"

Comment: Put the invisible 'does' 'has' etc at the front & the apparent need to write 'knows' vanishes too.

Comment: @Tetsujin Do you say "Anyone has a change?" (I meant has change)

Comment: No. I'm not even sure how to read that, as it stands. If you mean coins for the parking meter etc, then 'Anyone have change?'

Comment: I know how it's formulated. It's just thought my version was kinda the standard :-)

Comment: Then I had my own Lenglish!

Comment: There is no doubt that after "anyone" we should use a singular verb. And to ask a question we have to use "Does anyone have an extra apartment?" or "Does anyone know what happened?" But for spoken English we can use "Anyone knows what happened?" or "Anyone has an extra apartment?" But even saying so I have came across sentences like "Anyone have any idea?". I don't know if they are right or wrong. According to standard English Grammar they should be incorrect. Another thing in the quote that I don't like is this sentence - "Where is a great place to visit at the end of March?"

Comment: It should be written like "What is a great place to visit at the end of March?" But I don't know if the sentence with "where" is incorrect because I have seen sentences like this - "where is a good place to eat..?" - many times. So I ask native speakers to please tell us which ones are right and which ones are wrong.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics) for why it is not 'anyone knows...' or 'anyone has...'

Comment: @J.R. Just to clear any misunderstanding, let me get this straight, is "**Anyone knows what happened?**" correct? Could it be correct under any circumstances? I know the other form (elliptical) is "Anyone know what happened?" which is a short form of a standard question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *conversational deletion*, which John Lawler has addressed on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/24489).

Briefly, this is a 'rule' of conversational English which says that a speaker can chop off elementsat the beginning of an utterance which may be inferred from the context—primarily function words, "articles, dummies, auxiliaries, possessives, conditional if, and ... subject pronouns". In your example:

> <s>Does</s> anyone have an extra apartment there?

*Have* stays in the infinitive, because the *does* is inferred.  This might also be expressed

> <s>Has</s> anyone got an extra apartment there?

If the subject is inferrable, that can go, too:

> <s>Have you</s> got a spare pen?
>   <s>Will you</s> have a drink?

But as Prof. Lawler says,

> this phenomenon only occurs in **speaking** English, and in other informal communication systems like email and txting that work like speech. It is **not** good formal written style, except for reporting dialog in a story.

Comment: Is conversational deletion different from elliptical questions?

Comment: @starsplusplus I don't know exactly what you mean by 'elliptical questions'. Conversational deletion involves ellipsis, but as you may see from Prof. Lawler's Answer at the link, it is not restricted to questions: "Just been down to the corner" deletes "I have".

Comment: Ah, "elliptical questions" was a term I borrowed from the comments above. I assumed it meant I meant [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) at the start of a question. I'm not very familiar with all these terms :)

Comment: [Ellipsis](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ellipsis) +  sentence (Q, etc) = Elliptical Sentence ([Q](http://www.clas.ufl.edu/users/rthompso/interactionquestions.html), etc) - Links embedded

Comment: StoneyB Do I take it that "Anyone know**s** what happened?" can never be correct under any circumstance? From what I understand Tetsujin sees it is incorrect. I'm not sure about @J.R. though.

Comment: @learner Oh, sure, that could show up. It could represent "[Is there] anyone [who] knows what happened?" with *is there* a conversational deletion and *who* a colloquially acceptable deletion of a subject relative.

Comment: Would it help to mention that this left edge deletion generally only applies to function words?

Comment: @snailboat [JL lists](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972) "articles, dummies, auxiliaries, possessives, conditional *if*, and ... subject pronouns".

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, and all of those are function words :-)  But a specific list is even better!